# Print file contents on gnuplot

Tags: plot, textbox, gnuplot

I have a plot for data from one file, and in another file there is the average value. Is it possible to print out a textbox of the content of that second file to my plot as a string?

Comment: Can you post the content and structure of the file with the average value?

Comment: The whole file contains two lines:

Average value:
303.287

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set label 1 at graph 0.1, graph 0.9 system("cat secondfile")
```

Here the x position of the textbox would be 0.1 graph width and the y position would be 0.9 graph height, so the textbox will be in the upper left corner inside the graph.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I have low reputation, so can't mark your answer as helpful.